# i used DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI() in UWP project

Tags: uwp, share

This function show just few apps in panel not show all shareable apps in my laptop? How can I access all available apps in my desktop.

I tried many time but got no solution please help me

Answer (score 0):

> This function show just few apps in panel not show all shareable apps
>   in my laptop.

The system displays a list of possible target apps when a user invokes Share. In order to appear on the list, your app needs to declare that it supports the Share contract. This lets the system know that your app is available to receive content.

That means if you want to share your data to other apps, but other apps needs to declare that it supports the Share contract first, about how to declare, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/app-to-app/receive-data). That is, if other apps have declared that it accepts such a function shared by your app, so that it can receive data shared by your app and will appear in the sharing panel. So if you can't see other apps in the sharing panel, this is because those apps are not prepared for this and can't receive data from your app.